# Computing persistence number of an integer

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code that does the following:

> Multiplying the digits of an integer and continuing the process gives
>   the surprising result that the  sequence of products always arrives at
>   a single-digit number.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> 715 -> 35 -> 15 -> 5
>
> 88 -> 64 -> 24 -> 8
>
> 27 -> 14 -> 4
> ```
>
> The number of products necessary to reach the single-digit
>   number is called the  persistence  number of that integer. Thus 715
>   and 88 have a persistence number of 3, while 27 has  persistence 2.
>   Make a program to find the only two-digit number with persistence
>   greater than 3?

I was able to come up with a rough idea and the code is below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
num2=0
num3=0
num4=0

num=input("what is your number?")

while num in range(10,100):
    print 'step1'

    num1=num%10*num/10

    if num1-10>10:
        print 'step2'
        num2=num1%10*num1/10
    elif num2-num1>10:
        print 'step3'
        num3=num2%10*num2/10
    elif num3-num2>10:
        print 'step4'
        num4=num3%10*num3/10
    elif num4-num3>10:
        print 'step5'
        print num4
    else:
        break
```

The program is Python and I simply can't figure this out.  If someone could possibly help me I would appreciate it greatly!

Comment: @Adam Kayne: Given the way the problem is stated, I assume this is homework, so I've added the `homework` tag.  If this isn't the case, please feel free to edit and remove the tag.

Comment: Well it was for a robotics club but yes thank you I suppose it is homework :)

Comment: Were I less arrogant and pedantic, I could resist the urge to point out that the result described is hardly "surprising". ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a while or for loop to multiply the digits instead of hardcoding what to do with the first, second and so on digits.

In pseudocode...

```
productSoFar = 1
digitsLeftToMultipy = #the number
while there are digits left to multiply:
    get the next digit and
    update produtsSoFar and digitsLeftToMultiply
```

Also, use

```
10 <= n < 100
```

instead of

```
n in range(10, 100)
```

So you only do a couple of comparisons instead of a sequential lookup that takes time proportional to the length of the range.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are friends.

Consider a function, `getEnds(x)`, which when passed an integer, `x` will extract the first digit and the last digit (as integers) and return the result as a tuple in the form `(first_digit, last_digit)`. If `x` is a single-digit number the tuple will contain one element and be in the form `(x)`, otherwise it will be two. (A simple way to do this is to turn the number into a string, extract the first/last digit as a string, and then convert said strings back into numbers... however, there are many ways: just make sure to honor the function contract, as stated above and -- hopefully -- in the function documentation.)

Then, where `n` is the current number we are finding the persistence for:

```
ends = getEnds(n)
while ends contains two elements
   n = first element of ends times second element of ends
   ends = getEnds(n)
# while terminates when ends contained only one element
# now it's only a matter of "counting" the persistence
```

For added points, make sure this is in a -- [an] appropriately named/documented -- function as well and consider the use of a recursive function instead of a while-loop.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the digits of a number, convert it into a string first and reference them with array notation.

Comment: The OP can already solve his problem with the tools he has (loops and arithmetic operations) The is no need to complicate things with strings and arrays for now.

Comment: If he's trying to do something Pythonic, string manipulation is a lot simpler than doing a bunch of arithmetic operations to extract the digits.