# Python Persistent number

Tags: python, numbers, persistence

need some assistance to write a Persistent number program in Python to determine the smallest non-negative integer with a persistence
(715 ---> 35 ---> 15 ---> 5) of 3, then 4, then 5, then 6, then 7. With an output with the following format:

```
The smallest integer with a persistence of 3 is: 39
The smallest integer with a persistence of 4 is: xx
The smallest integer with a persistence of 5 is: xxx
The smallest integer with a persistence of 6 is: xxxx
The smallest integer with a persistence of 7 is: xxxxx
```

Any code links or leads would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It would have been helpful to provide an explanation or a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number) to an explanation of what the persistence of a number is, rather than just providing an inscrutable 715->35->15->5 sequence. Also, if you think this site is a place for people to just provide your code for you, you're on the wrong website.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973690/computing-persistence-number-of-an-integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973690/computing-persistence-number-of-an-integer)

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for the link.  I'd only seen the add-the-digits kind of persistence before.  I didn't know there were other kinds, like the multiply-the-digits version the OP must have meant.

Answer (score -1):

```
def main():

    low_limit = 3
    high_limit = 7

    for limit in range(low_limit, high_limit+1):
        number = 1
        while persistence(number) < limit:
            number += 1
            print('The smallest integer with a persistence of', limit, 'is:', number)

def persistence(x):
    pcount = 0    # counting the p from 0
    while x>=10:
        y=x       # temp copy of x 
        z=1       # z holds the value of y as being broken down and multplied
        while (y!=0):
            z=z*(y%10)     # stripping last number and mult by last z value
            y=y//10       # integer division, dropping off the last digit
        x=z    
        pcount +=1
    return pcount

main()
```